# Callout response BadRequest

Tags: apex, callout

I am running following code in my execute anonymous Window

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://orderdb.herokuapp.com/orders.svc/Orders');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/atom+xml');
req.setMethod('GET');
System.debug(req);
Http h = new Http(); 
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res);
```

response I am getting is

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

But if i paste url https://orderdb.herokuapp.com/orders.svc/Orders in browser it is giving me response.

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're trying to get the response, shouldn't your Http Method be GET?

Comment: Yes, I am trying GET method, i will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Accept header. It states what you're expecting in response. Content-Type is for request.

```
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');
```

You can read more for Http headers from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).